# JS variable to PHP variable without buttons or refresh

Tags: javascript, php

I've searched for over an hour and tried many examples but none do what I need. From JavaScript I can display the necessary variable in PHP or HTML with `<b id="citynm"></b>` but I need to make citynm `$citynm`. I've tried looking in AJAX for the first time but could only get it to work with a button click or page refresh.

I need to run the JavaScript to get citynm and then make it into `$citynm` for PHP use on any page without running the JS again. The JS is only run once upon entering the site. But the `$citynm` will be run on several pages in different needs (such as `echo "You live in ".$citynm`).

Comment: *"I've tried looking in AJAX for the first time but could only get it to work with a button click or page refresh."* I think you haven't used Ajax properly then. Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started. If you want to persist a variable across requests, you might want to look at sessions: http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php.

Comment: hate to nitpick but the Mozilla link is not working

Comment: MDN seems to have technical problems right now.

Comment: I guess you must know the fact that javascript is a client side script and PHP is a server side script. So,javascript can be executed directly by the browser, whereas PHP cannot, in such case, the request is passed on to apache for processing. Hence any php actions cannot be done without refreshing a page! You need to keep this in consideration. May be try storing in js cookies then use it in php.

Comment: @Genx88 According to searching here and via google it is possible but must be done with ajax or the like. The issue I'm having is that the example scripts all required a user input to accomplish this. The javascript I use is run once on loading and never again. The variable produce by the javascript (which can be displayed automatically by '<b id="citynm"></b>') needs to also automatically change to the PHP variable '$citynm' without user input

Comment: Anything you can do as response to some user interaction, you can also do on page load.

Comment: Your variable name seems to refer to the cityname. Will it be so? How is the value determined, if there is no user input?

Comment: The JS script I'm using is getting the 'citynm' by geolocation. It is run upon entry to the page and spits out 'citynm' here: <code> var cityname = city.short_name;
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            document.getElementById("citynm").innerHTML = cityname;
        }
</code> When the JS script is done, it goes to the html body and displays <code><body>
You live in <b id="citynm"></b>. 
</body>
</code> The 'citynm' is in BOLD obviously. I need this code to work instead <code> <?php echo"You live in" . $citynm; ?></code>

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to store the value you want for citynm into a session variable as below:

```
$_SESSION['citynm'] = $citynm
```

You have to do this either at page load, or by ajax. Then, you can use $_SESSION['citynm'] in any pages you want since its global.

Answer (score 0):

**USECASE 1: via user input**

in your html document:

```
<input type="text" name="citynm" id="citynm" value="Brussels">
```

inside your javascript file (using jquery here for readability):

```
(function(){

    $('#citynm').on('blur',function(){
    // when the input value has changed, post its value to server.
var citynm = $(this).val();
        $.post('http://domain.com/path/to/your/php/file.php',{citynm: citynm},function(data){

// if the request is successful, the following script will be executed.
alert("server said: "+data);
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

And inside the file.php file:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['citynm']) && strlen($_POST['citynm'])>0){
      $_SESSION['citynm'] = $_POST['citynm'];
    }
echo "citynm is ".  $_SESSION['citynm'];

?>
```

**USECASE 2: no userinput**

```
   var cityname = city.short_name; 
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { document.getElementById("citynm").innerHTML = cityname; }

    (function(){

                $.post('http://domain.com/path/to/your/php/file.php',{citynm: cityname},function(data){

        // if the request is successful, the following script will be executed.
        alert("server said: "+data);
                });
        })(jQuery);
```

Comment: JQuery and Ajax are extremely new to me. I have tried to add your USERCASE 2 into my functioning JS script at the end and also when it creates the 'citynm' neither worked. I tried your code as its own JS script which didn't work either. Where should it be located please?

Comment: First, make sure your html page loads jquery, using a script tag pointing to your jquery file. See http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/ for more info on including jquery.  
Right after the "your code goes here" part, include the code of usecase 2 (which i have just adapted to use your geolocalized variable).

Comment: I'm certain I followed your instructions to the letter but the only display I get is the     <a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
The page source is at [link](http://albertaxchange.com/citynm.php)[/link]

Comment: you have to launch my code when/after your geolocalisation script has been done.

Comment: Try this code: http://jsfiddle.net/NtqDD/   I added the ajax call to the part of your code that executes if the geolocalization went ok.

Comment: still no display :( unless I put your code in the wrong place